# JSON object passed in the php script

Tags: php, json, urldecode

I have a PHP script and JSON object with some values is being passed in the the PHP get function. I have tried different ways to decode JSON but failed.
The code I have tried is :

```
$get_order_info = $_GET['orderInfo'];
$order_json = json_decode($get_order_info, true);

echo $order_json->{'mealsInfo'};
```

The JSON string is :

```
{
  "mealsInfo" : [
    {
      "DrinkSize" : 1,
      "MealQuantity" : 1,
      "MealId" : "57",
      "addons" : [
        {
          "addOnID" : 1,
          "addonTitle" : "spicy"
        },
        {
          "addOnID" : 3,
          "addonTitle" : "Thin Base"
        }
      ],
      "FriesSize" : 2
    }
  ],
  "TransactionID" : "56",
  "OrerType" : "PickUp",
  "frenchiseInfo" : {
    "storeName" : "Dubai Downtown Franchise",
    "OrderCollectionTime" : "06:12:50 PM",
    "FranchiseId" : "4"
  },
  "customerinfo" : {
    "Instructions" : "Test instruction",
    "CustomerName’" : "Talat",
    "Area" : "al Riga",
    "City" : "Dubai",
    "Phone" : "0559467800",
    "Email" : "test@test.com",
    "Address" : "al nouf tower"
  },
  "status" : "pending",
  "totalPrice" : 51
}
```

Can somebody please help me to decode it in a correct way?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: What is the output when you var_dump($order_json) without giving any index?

Comment: What is the error you got echo $order_json->{'mealsInfo'};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `true` as second parameter to `json_decode`, it will return and array not object. Try with -

```
$order_json = json_decode($get_order_info, true);

echo $order_json['mealsInfo'][0]['DrinkSize'];
```

Comment: its not working its giving me this error :
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\learning\service\submit_new_order.php on line 13
Array

Comment: Sorry for that. `$order_json['mealsInfo']` is an array with nested arrays. Check the update.

Comment: @b0s3 When true, it returns object

Comment: ok, now its giving me the full JSON. how can I get the values for specific keys in the string pls help?

Comment: @IshaS *When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.*

Comment: its error "undefined index", and how can i get the values of var dump in string?

Comment: Add the output - `var_dump($order_json['mealsInfo']);`.

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["DrinkSize"]=> int(1) ["MealQuantity"]=> int(1) ["MealId"]=> string(2) "57" ["addons"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["addOnID"]=> int(1) ["addonTitle"]=> string(5) "spicy" } [1]=> array(2) { ["addOnID"]=> int(3) ["addonTitle"]=> string(9) "Thin Base" } } ["FriesSize"]=> int(2) } }

Comment: @b0s3 ,My requriement is not to print or echo the json ,,,i have to split it in to the string... so the var_dump function will not be suitable for me?

Comment: How you want the string?

Comment: I mean i need the value of each tag i.e. drink size,meal quantity in separate variable ,,so how this function will work for me?

Comment: It is an array now. simple loop through it and generate the string.

Comment: @b0s3 how can i get the addons info inside the mealinfo?

Comment: You need to use `loop` for array `$order_json['mealsInfo'][0]['addons']`

Answer (score 0):

```
$get_order_info = $_POST['orderInfo'];
$order_json = json_decode($get_order_info, true);

echo $order_json->{'mealsInfo'};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$order_json = json_decode($get_order_info, true);

var_dump($order_json->{'mealsInfo'});
```